# What should I use for configuration management on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, aws-opsworks

I am trying to find a solution for configuration management using AWS OpsWorks. What I can see is AWS offers three services for OpsWorks

1. Chef Automate
2. Puppet
3. AWS stacks

I have read basics of all three of them but unable to compare between three of them. I am unable to understand when to use which solution.

I want to implemnet a solution for my multiple EC2 instances, using which I can deliver updates to all my instances from a central repository(github). And, rollback changes if needed.

So following are my queries:

1. Which of the three solutions is best for this use case?
2. What should I use if my instances are in different regions?

I am unable to find anything useful on these topics so that I can make my decision. It would be great if I can get links to some useful articles as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) and [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) are a great resource, I use them everyday to configure AMI's and build out all my infrastructure.

Terraform - Configuration Management for Infrastructure, it allows you to provision all the AWS, Azure, GCE components you needs to run your application.

Packer - Creates reusable images by pre installing software that is common to your applications.

Ansible - pre and post provisioning configuration management. You can use Ansible with Packer to provision software in an AMI, then if needed, use Ansible to configure it after provisioning. There is no need for a chef server or puppet master, you can run Ansible from your desktop if you have access to the cloud servers.

This examples provisions all the infrastructure for a Wordpress site, and uses Ansible to configure it post provisioning.

https://github.com/strongjz/tf-wordpress

All of this as well can automated in a [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) or with other Continous Deployment tools like CircleCI etc.

Ansible has no restriction on regions, neither does Terraform. Packer is a local build tool or on a CD server.

Examples:

https://www.terraform.io/intro/examples/aws.html

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples

https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/build-image.html